# Nested ListView with ScrollController Not Scrolling

Tags: flutter, listview, nested, scrollcontroller

I am building a widget with a custom navigation bar which includes a `Stack` with the main body and the navigation bar.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _buildBody(),
        _buildNavigationBar(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The body consists of a `ListView` with a header and a `ListView.builder` nested below that for the contents.

```
Widget _buildBody() {
    return ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 44.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
      controller: _scrollController,
      children: [
        Opacity(
          opacity: 1.0 - _navigationBarOpacity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
            child: _buildHeaderTitle(
              title: widget.title,
              fontSize: _largeFontSize,
              fontWeight: _largeFontWeight,
              color: widget.color,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: widget.itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return widget.itemBuilder(context, index);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I'm using a `ScrollController` on the primary/root `ListView` in order to fade my navigation bar in and out. This works as expected.

However, **adding the `ScrollController` to the `ListView` stops any scrolling/bouncing interaction. How can I fix this?**

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        double min = 0.0;
        double max = 25.0;
        _navigationBarOpacity = (_scrollController.offset - min) / (max - min);
        if (_navigationBarOpacity < 0) _navigationBarOpacity = 0;
        if (_navigationBarOpacity > 1) _navigationBarOpacity = 1;
      });
    });  
  }
```

---

*Interestingly, if I move the `ScrollController` to the nestedt `ListView.builder`, the root `ListView` scrolls/bounces, but then I can no longer adjust the UI based on the offset as it's on the wrong `ListView`.*

*Another point of interest, the root `ListView` scrolls normally if it's children exceed it's height. However, there are cases where it won't have that and I'd expect it just to bounce on pulling.*

---

### Update

Even if I remove the stack and nested `ListView`, a simple, singlular `ListView` with the `ScrollController` won't scroll on drag, without it, it will. This is the root issue that needs resolving.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 44.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
        controller: _scrollController,
        children: [
          Opacity(
            opacity: 1.0 - _navigationBarOpacity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
              child: _buildHeaderTitle(
                title: widget.title,
                fontSize: _largeFontSize,
                fontWeight: _largeFontWeight,
                color: widget.color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
```

Comment: Consider using `CustomScrollView` with `SliverAppBar` and `SliverList` (`SliverChildBuilderDelegate`)

Comment: This doesn't create the effect I desire, nor does it provide me the flexibility to customise it further to me needs going forward. Hence the need to resolve, or at least understand why I am facing the `ScrollController` issue.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by wrapping the parent `ListView` in a `PrimaryScrollController` then setting `primary = true` on the `ListView`.

This lets `PrimaryScrollController` manage the controller, but the `ListView` maintains typical scrolling behaviour as it no longer manages the `ScrollController`.

See Flutter docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/primary.html